# How Can I Get Provisioning Profiles on New Computer without a Backup of Them?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

My macbook died.  Seriously died.  Very suddenly.  A new logic board doesn't help it.  I have a backup of my projects which HOPEFULLY I can copy over to the new mac and I have the hard drive intact.

**However I don't have any provisioning profiles saved.**  My new macbook is coming soon and I am anticipating HUGE headaches.  Is there a way to create new provisioning profiles and salvage them from the dead hard-drive? Can I create all new provisioning profiles and use them on my existing projects?  Can anyone suggest how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can always re-download your provisioning profiles from the Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles tab on [The Apple Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com).

Your real problem will be the certificates. If you've lost your private keys, then you'll have to regenerate them and then regenerate the provisioning profiles.

To do this, you go to the Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles section of [The Apple Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com), click on Certificates. Delete the lost certificates, then click "+" to create new ones (this will involve Keychain.app).

This will invalidate your provision profiles, so Edit them to use the new certificates and re-download/open/select in your Xcode projects.

Comment: Thanks.  But how do you regenerate private keys?